# How to downgrade libgtk3 to pre-3.16 on Debian Testing?

Tags: debian

On Debian Testing, I made the mistake of upgrading libgtk-3-0 which uninstalled gtk3-engines-oxygen. I was not able to re-install gtk3-engines-oxygen afterwards. According to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195882 , this is because GTK 3.16 dropped support for the theming system gtk3-engines-oxygen uses which left to gtk3-engines-oxygen author (understandably) too discouraged to bother rewriting the theme.

My old version of libgtk-3-0 and libgtk-3-common was 3.14.4-2, but when I try to reinstall that version  from apt-get or aptitude, I just get:

Unable to find a version "3.14.4-2" for the package "libgtk-3-common"

How do I get a pre-3.16 libgtk3 installed again?

Answer (score 1):

You can get older versions from snapshot.debian.org. Specifically, you want the [Source package gtk+3.0](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/gtk%2B3.0/) page.

Having said that, you aren't going to have much success keeping them around. You won't find it practical to try to maintain these packages yourself.